# Remove duplicates from column A based on existing values in column B using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I need to input data in column A and column B and get the data that's in column A **but not in column B** written to column C.

Examples of what I need:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Comment: P.S I need this in VBA because it's going to be used for lists of over 10,000 cells and a formula will jam the entire excel.

Comment: The way to start such a project is to list out the steps, in macro format and using only remarks, like, `' Take one address from column A` and `'search for it in column B` and `IF found, skip to next` and `ELSE write the name in column C`. In this way you will have "code" which will enable you to get stuck. Once you are stuck you can find help on this site.

Comment: I did as you say but didn't get stuck, running the command does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different and faster approach without looping through cells on the sheet would be this...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x, y(), dict
Dim i As Long, j As Long
x = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Columns("C").ClearContents
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    dict.Item(x(i, 2)) = ""
Next i
j = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
        ReDim Preserve y(1 To j)
        y(j) = x(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Range("C1").Resize(UBound(y), 1) = Application.Transpose(y)
End Sub
```

Comment: Much faster indeed.
If you add `dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""` inside the `If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1))...` block,
then possible duplicates in `A` column will not slip into the output.

Comment: I think having duplicate in the column C is OP's requirement as per what OP has shown as the desired output. And that's why dict.item was not included in the code as this would only have unique items in the column C. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the code file behind your sheet and change `CommandButton1` to the name of your button.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim r As Range, matched_ As Variant, counter_ As Long

    'Loop in each cell in Column A
    For Each r In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
            'Loop for a matching value in Column B
            matched_ = Application.Match(r.Value, Columns(2), 0)

            'If match not found, write the value in Column C
            If IsError(matched_) Then
                counter_ = counter_ + 1
                Range("C" & counter_) = r.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: You're a god! Thank you!
Do you need to do anything to the code to put it in an ActiveX command button?

Comment: Place it in the code file behind your worksheet and change the `CommandButton1` if named differently.

Comment: It look like if there are duplicates in column `A`, they all will appear in `C`.